# Renaming cached RDD/Dataframe description in Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

In **Scala**, there's a method called `setName` which enables users to prescribe a user-friendly display of their cached RDDs/Dataframes under Spark UI's `Storage` tab. (I'm using Databricks for this operation)

**Note:** I've already attempted to use `setName` method available using the **Python API**, but this doesn't appear to update the descriptions of the RDD name in the Storage tab in Spark UI (each "RDD Name" is shown in query form) -

Does anyone know how we can display this in a user friendly manner? If no mechanism is currently available feel free to also let me know this!

Answer (score 2):

it's the same for Python - just use `setName` function on `pyspark.RDD` (see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.setName.html#pyspark.RDD.setName)):

```py
df.rdd.setName("myName")
```

Comment: I've tried this attempt already but this doesn't appear to have updated the descriptions of the RDD name in the Storage tab in Spark UI (each "RDD Name" is shown in query form) - how do we display this in a user friendly manner?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to create a SQL view and using the SQL context to cache, that works for me on pyspark.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView(name)
sqlContext.cacheTable(name)
```